# editing provisioning profile impact

Tags: ios, provisioning

I want to edit existing in-house provisioning profile in developer member center

Will it affects users who already installed my app with this provision profile ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create new provisioning... Just curious.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I don't want to change Jenkins settings :)

Answer (score 0):

> No. it will not affect users who already installed my app. it
>   provisioning profile just allow to install app on device. in case you
>   edit valid provisioning profile and code sign it will not affect
>   already installed my app.

Answer (score 0):

No, editing in provisioning profile will not affect on installed app, because the app installed in device is no more linked up with your existing provisioning profile.

but instead of editing in existing provisioning profile, you can add make new provisioning profile for your application and that's the best practice to make record about our created provisioning profile.